# Sass loop output string instead of number

Tags: css, loops, math, sass

I want to make a loop that create 8 different classes with same the same include but a different value. Here's my code:

```
@for $i from 1 through 8 {
  $baseDelay: 0.4;
  .fade-in-#{$i} {
    @include animationDelay(#{$baseDelay}+((#{$i}-1)/2)s);
  }
}
```

I should get this as the output for the first class:

```
.fade-in-1 {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.9s;
  animation-delay: 0.9s;
}
```

But instead I get this as the first output:

```
.fade-in-1 {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.4+(1-0.5) s;
  animation-delay: 0.4+(1-0.5) s;
}
```

Can someone help me? I think the problem is caused because Sass think that something in the sum is a sting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this code.

This is what my mixin looks like

```
@mixin animationDelay($var) {
  -webkit-animation-delay: $var;
  animation-delay: $var;
}
```

And this is what my for loop looks like

```
@for $i from 1 through 8 {
  $baseDelay: 0.4;
  .fade-in-#{$i} {
    @include animationDelay( ($baseDelay + ($i - 1)/2) + s); 
    // I did the calculation first before adding the s for seconds
  }
}
```

And here's the result

```
.fade-in-1 {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.4s;
  animation-delay: 0.4s; }

.fade-in-2 {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0.9s;
  animation-delay: 0.9s; }

.fade-in-3 {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 1.4s;
  animation-delay: 1.4s; }

 .fade-in-4 {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 1.9s;
  animation-delay: 1.9s; }

 .fade-in-5 {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 2.4s;
  animation-delay: 2.4s; }

 .fade-in-6 {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 2.9s;
  animation-delay: 2.9s; }

 .fade-in-7 {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 3.4s;
  animation-delay: 3.4s; }

 .fade-in-8 {
  -webkit-animation-delay: 3.9s;
  animation-delay: 3.9s; }
```